# Regex rule for URL redirect case and directories

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am looking for help with the following URL redirect configuration with RegEx:

Current URL: http://support.olddomain.com/en-US/company/help_files/AB012345
New URL: http://support.newdomain.com/articles/CDE678910

The problem is that we also have case issues and other directories:

support.olddomain.com/**en-us**/company/help_files/AB012345 - lowercase en_us
support.olddomain.com/en-us/**C**ompany/help_files/AB012345 - capitalized Company 
support.olddomain.com/en-us/company/help_files/AB012345?title=Article+Title - additional parameters

support.olddomain.com/en-us/company/all_files/AB012345 - on all_files, not just hel_files

Thus, we want to redirect any URL with the path AB###### to the proper page on newdomain.com with the following conditions:

1. Works for http and https
2. Ignores capitalization
3. Ignores parameters
4. Works for both all_files and help_files directories.

Any help is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in notepad++
CTRL+H

FIND: `^([\w+\.]+)\/(?=.*AB.*)`
Replace: `newdomain.com/`

Answer (score 0):

I made a regular expression match all samples.

^(http(s)?:\/\/)?support\.olddomain\.com\/en\-[uU]s\/[cC]ompany\/(help_files|all_files)\/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}(\/.+)?$

[You can test here](http://rubular.com/r/equT501ISd)

Note: If you use c, c++, c#, java, etc remember replace al single back slash "\" by double back slash "\\"

Comment: ^(http(s)?:\\/\\/)?support\\.olddomain\\.com\\/en\\-[uU]s\\/[cC]ompany\\/(help_files|all_files)\\/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}(\\/.+)?$